# Bing Maps API V8 - map.layers.clear() method removes the polyline from map view

Tags: maps, bing, bing-maps

Some time ago, the **map.layers.clear()** method would not remove the polyline from the map, but now, after some Bing update, the polyline is being removed when **map.layers.clear()** is called. How can I solve this?

> Map initialize

```
var map = new Microsoft.Maps.Map(document.getElementById('myMap'), {
    credentials: 'Your Bing Maps Key',
    center: new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.606209, -122.332071),
    zoom: 12
});
```

> Here add pushpins

```
// Add pushpins
function addPushpins() {
    // Generate an array of 10 random pushpins within current map bounds
    var pushpins = Microsoft.Maps.TestDataGenerator.getPushpins(10, map.getBounds());
    var layer = new Microsoft.Maps.Layer();
    layer.add(pushpins);
    map.layers.insert(layer);
}
```

> Here is update direction callback

```
// On update directions callback
function onUpdateDirections() {
    map.layers.clear();
}
```

> Call addPushpins function

```
addPushpins();
```

> Here is the Bing Maps Direction Manager sample code

```
Microsoft.Maps.loadModule('Microsoft.Maps.Directions', function() {
    var directionsManager = new Microsoft.Maps.Directions.DirectionsManager(map);

    // Set Route Mode to driving
    directionsManager.setRequestOptions({
        routeMode: Microsoft.Maps.Directions.RouteMode.driving
    });

    // Callback for on update directions
    Microsoft.Maps.Events.addHandler(directionsManager, 'directionsUpdated', onUpdateDirections);

    var waypoint1 = new Microsoft.Maps.Directions.Waypoint({
        address: 'Redmond',
        location: new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.67683029174805, -122.1099624633789)
    });
    var waypoint2 = new Microsoft.Maps.Directions.Waypoint({
        address: 'Seattle',
        location: new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.59977722167969, -122.33458709716797)
    });

    directionsManager.addWaypoint(waypoint1);
    directionsManager.addWaypoint(waypoint2);

    // Set the element in which the itinerary will be rendered
    directionsManager.setRenderOptions({
        itineraryContainer: document.getElementById('printoutPanel')
    });

    directionsManager.calculateDirections();
});
```

**UPDATE - Removes partials pushpins**

```
// Map initialize
var map, pushpins, layer;

map = new Microsoft.Maps.Map(document.getElementById('myMap'), {
    credentials: 'Your Bing Maps Key',
    center: new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.606209, -122.332071),
    zoom: 12
});

// Here is the Bing Maps Direction Manager sample code
Microsoft.Maps.loadModule('Microsoft.Maps.Directions', function() {
    var directionsManager = new Microsoft.Maps.Directions.DirectionsManager(map);

    // Set Route Mode to driving
    directionsManager.setRequestOptions({
        routeMode: Microsoft.Maps.Directions.RouteMode.driving
    });

    var waypoint1 = new Microsoft.Maps.Directions.Waypoint({
        address: 'Redmond',
        location: new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.67683029174805, -122.1099624633789)
    });
    var waypoint2 = new Microsoft.Maps.Directions.Waypoint({
        address: 'Seattle',
        location: new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.59977722167969, -122.33458709716797)
    });

    directionsManager.addWaypoint(waypoint1);
    directionsManager.addWaypoint(waypoint2);

    // Callback for on update directions
    Microsoft.Maps.Events.addHandler(directionsManager, 'directionsUpdated', onUpdateDirections);

    directionsManager.calculateDirections();
});

// On update directions callback
function onUpdateDirections() {
    clearLayers();

    window.setTimeout(function() {
        addPushpins();
    }, 2000);
}

// Add pushpins
function addPushpins() {
    // Generate an array of 10 random pushpins within current map bounds
    pushpins = Microsoft.Maps.TestDataGenerator.getPushpins(10, map.getBounds());
    layer = new Microsoft.Maps.Layer();
    layer.add(pushpins);
    map.layers.insert(layer);
}

// Clear layers
function clearLayers() {
    // map.layers.clear();
    if (layer !== undefined) {
        var currentPrimitives = layer.getPrimitives();

        /* remove those that are Pushpins */
        for (var i = 0; i < currentPrimitives.length; i++) {
            var entity = currentPrimitives[i];
            if (entity instanceof Microsoft.Maps.Pushpin){
                layer.remove(entity);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is to be expected. It not clearing in the past would have been considered a bug. If you want to clear your layers, but leave the directions you have two options. Clear the layers before calculating the directions, or clear the individual layer rather than all layers in the map.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for reply. But when I clears the layer on route update (drag & drop), map.layers.clear() removes the polyline. I'm trying to clear layer pushpins, but some pushpins stay on the map. See UPDATE.

Comment: What's wrong with doing this: `function clearLayers() { layer.clear(); }`

Comment: This function is not removing all the pushpins from  the map. Please test on Bing Maps Interactive SDK to see this behavior.

Comment: Are you talking about the route pushpins? If so, those are part of the route. Use directionManager.clearAll() or directionsManager.clearDisplay(). These are documented here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt750375.aspx

Comment: Thanks for replying again. But I'm do not talk about the route pushpins. I have a route and I added some pushpins around the map. And I need to clean those pushpins sometimes to put others, without removing my current route. I have many other types of layer, like pushpins, heatmaps and cluster layers too. When I change the route line, through drag and drop, I need to clear those elements.

Comment: I just tried your code and doing layer.clear() removed the pushpins without removing the directions, which is expected.

Answer (score 1):

You could examine your layer, get the primitives from it and remove only the pins. Something like the following:

```
var currentPrimitives =  layer.getPrimitives();

/* remove those that are Pushpins */
for (var i = 0; i < currentPrimitives.length; i++) {
    var entity = currentPrimitives[i];
    if (entity instanceof Microsoft.Maps.Pushpin){
        layer.remove(entity);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply!

I'm testing your solution, but doesn't removes all the pushpins.

See UPDATE.